# How a user can change password when signup with google, facebook, apple and other social sites in firebase (web/react)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

When users signup with social sites like google, Facebook and apple, Is there any possibility that they can change their password and next time when they want to login they just use their email(used for that particular social site account) and updated password ??

If yes then how they can do it??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user first makes account using google, signs out, then logs in for the first time by just entering email and leaving password blank (or entering the new password they want to set),
you will have to link their google account with their Email_Password account.

But the only way you can link accounts is if the user is currently signed in to their google account.

So the only way you can enable the feature you have in mind is by showing a prompt (after user presses login button) informing the user that a google account was found with the same email address and mention that if you want to link the account, they sign in with google (with the google button in the prompt).

So they click on the google button, you get their google credentials, now you can link both the accounts.

Flow of your code when user clicks on login -

1. Check if a google (or other social media) account with same email exists, but no email_password account with same email exists
2. If not both the above conditions are true then just do what you are already doing
3. If both the above conditions are true, bring up a prompt, which says you already have an account with same email, sign in through google to continue. It should have two buttons, one smaller cancel button, and another larger google button, clicking on which you can sign them in with google.
4. Now make credentials for their new Email_Password account using the email and password they entered earlier (if they didnt enter a password earlier, ask what password they want to keep in a new prompt).
5. Link these credentials with their google account.

If you don't want to use this approach then you can simply keep an option to add a password in their account settings.